# Can a button both redirect and perform a function with asynchronous JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, material-ui

I have reviewed a few similar posts on here but everything I have found so far is using href to redirect to a totally new webpage.

I have a button in my JavaScript code which uses the Material-UI `<Link>`

```
<Button component={Link} to="/ratings" className={classes.addImage} onClick={this.submitScore}>
```

This button both redirects the webpage and calls a function which initiates a server request.  Now this code seemed to be running fine, both redirecting and running its `onClick` function.  However I recently discovered that running my code when not on WiFi often results in my image upload request to be ignored.  I've been trouble shooting this for a little while and my current theory is the cell data is slower and the page is rerouting before the upload request gets called.

Although this doesn't quite make sense to me.  It seems like the code should either run after the Link is called or not, but what I am seeing is the image upload request work while on WiFi but work infrequently while on cell data.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Here is the onClick function if it is helpful:

```
submitScore = () => {
    console.log(this.state)
    this.props.dispatch({type: 'SUBMIT_SCORE', payload: {ratings: this.props.scores, user_id : this.props.user.id, name: this.state.beerName, url: this.state.filename, notes: this.state.notes, filename: `${this.props.user.id}_${Date.now()}`}})
    // this.props.dispatch({type: 'ADD_PICTURE', payload: {picture: this.state.imgSrc, filename: `${this.props.user.id}_${Date.now()}`}})
    axios.get('/picture', {params: {filetype: this.state.imageType, filename: this.state.filename}})
    .then(response =>{
        var signedUrl = response.data;
        console.log(response)
        console.log(signedUrl)
        var headers= {
              'Content-Type': this.state.imageType,
            };

        console.log(...this.state.imageType)
        return axios.put(signedUrl, this.state.newfile, {headers:headers});
    })
    .then(function (result) {
        console.log(result,'success');
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err, 'fail');
    });
    swal({
        title: "Good job!",
        text: "You clicked the button!",
        icon: "success",
        timer: 2000,
    });
}
```

Comment: If the redirect is supposed to happen after the request completes, why not programmatically redirect in your "then" callback where you log the success result?

Comment: @AlvinAbia this is probably best practice and I agree that I should update my code. Any idea what’s causing the inconsistencies with this issue?

Comment: I'm not sure what `swal` does, but you might have given yourself a static timer of 2 seconds. `timer: 2000` If the request completes in time there are no issues, but if it takes longer than 2 seconds you might run into trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of linking to a new page in your button, can you set it up so you redirect on success?

```
.then(function (result) {
    console.log(result,'success');
    window.location.assign('/ratings'); // <-- Redirect here
})
```

You would need to remove the link from your button.

Comment: I am going to give this a try and see if it fixes the problem. Any idea what would cause the inconsistencies between WiFi and cell data though?

Comment: @user8735495 It may be a latency issue like you mentioned earlier. You are using promises to do a GET request followed by a PUT request. If your GET request takes too long to send back a response you will redirect before the PUT request is sent.